# Three layer dropdowns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Would it be possible using css bootstrap to recreate this style of menu I am using bootstrap and so far I have the top bar just with the two tabs and drop downs. I also see to show a drop down as in the administrator link you see and also a settings cog.

The blue icons buttons shoud be drop downs till the last item. I have posted my initial code on pastbin as the editor here was turning them into elements. Can someone advise me on how to stop that from hapening.

[image]
Code

```
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-home icon-white"></i> Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cassed Dimensions Portal</a></li>
                        <li><a href=""  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Configruation Items</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Latest Products</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Popular Products</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>          
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Membership<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Personal Membership</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Premium Membership</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Offers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>



     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#about">Right</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Right</a></li>
    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
  </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
</div><!-- /.navbar -->
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51106/how-to-post-code-in-so,  
http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help -- Short answer: use the `{}` button in the toolbar after selecting code.

Comment: @PaulRoub thanks budy aprecaite that no about four tabs didnt no that did it thanks and thanks

Comment: Here's a multi-level bootstrap menu: http://jsfiddle.net/chirayu45/YXkUT/16/. Here's something that may help you with this project or not, but it's handy to have http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/

Comment: why was my account bared can someone tell me